Is the word "done" needed in "what I done found"?
There is a dialogue in Killers Of The Flower Moon (2023):

Ramsey: Whoo-hoo. Partner. Look what I done found in the possum hole.

Is the word "done" needed?


... what I done found ...

Some users in some other sites say this use done found is mainly in some AAVE dialects and in certain parts of the America.
Edit
Google Books lists some of the publications.  Looking through some of them, I feel that done doesn't add value to the sentences.

Look what I found in the possum hole.

is perfectly fine.

Not just AAVE but also 'South East US white rural white'?

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  I don't know about the regions that use this.

Note that some of the British occurrences are false positives, where done is at the end of one sentence and Found at the beginning of another.

@KateBunting - I would say so as well, especially considering that Google Ngrams get their data by indexing printed books, or perhaps more exactly printed material. This means that results from searches for features of mainly spoken English may not be reliable (they may find quoted speech in e.g. novels, and that's a minefield!) Example: One old gray-headed woman, long past work, [..] rose, and leaning on her staff, said—“Well, chil’en! Well, I’m mighty glad to hear ye all and see ye all once more, ’cause I don’t know when I’ll be gone to glory; but I’ve done got ready, chil’en

Thanks, @Kate Bunting and
Michael Harvey.  I've incorporated your comments.

Note, Killers of the Flower Moon is set in 1920s Oklahoma. While this pattern may be found today, it was far more common and far more geographically widespread in the past. Given the setting, it seems irrelevant to even bring up British usages. I'm no expert, but I suspect like many AmE rural usages, especially Appalachian, it has roots in (perhaps archaic) Scottish and Irish usages. I could perhaps imagine it in the mouths of James Herriot's Yorkshire farmers.

Thanks,  @Andy Bonner.   I've deleted the Ngram, which was irrelevant to answering the OP's question on the necessity of done.

This use of done with the past participle is a characteristic of the dialect spoken by uneducated southerners in the US, black and white alike.
For example:

'If TomTom had hid that iron in his bed, you ought to done found it three weeks ago,' Mr. Snopes says. 'So suppose you look in that corn-crib where I told you to look.'

from the short story  "Centaur in Brass" by William  Faulkner, published in 1932. The character Snopes is a white man.  Faulkner won the Nobel Prize in Literature in 1949. (Somewhere on ELL there's a link to a video of Faulkner being interviewed by some University of Virginia linguists about his use of dialect. If I can find the question, I'll link to it.)
From a scholarly paper by James A. Harrison published in 1884 in  Anglia: Journal Of English Philology entitled "Negro English", which presents a description of many of the features of the language (but be warned, as might be expected it is not "woke" in its outlook):

... if one happened to be talking to a native with one's eyes shut it would be impossible to say whether a Negro or a white person were responding.
(vol. 7, p. 250)

You hear this southern dialect in the film because many southerners  migrated to Oklahoma in the 19th century and there was considerable interchange (often hostile, sometimes peaceful) between those former southerners and the native tribes that had been resettled to Oklahoma.

This is accurate. No doubt about it. Although it would be  useful mention used with action and non-action verbs: done seen, done been, done gone, etc.

I would go so far as to say that in times past this usage was not limited to the South or southern transplants, but common enough in rural or low-tone dialect throughout the midwest and west, to the point that it was not then solely a "Southern dialect." I still haven't read the book or seen the movie, though I mean to, so I'm not sure whether Ramsey has migrated from the Southeast, but I would find the usage believable even if he were born in OK.

@AndyBonner Ramsey himself need not have migrated from the South. There had been large numbers of southerners in Oklahoma, Texas, and Arkansas since after the Civil War.  See Wikipedia on "Little Dixie":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Dixie_(Oklahoma)
